# Comparing a portion of 2 Peter 3:4 to a portion of John 19:25

Tags: greek, 2-peter

When comparing the five-word parsed phrase in 2 Peter 3:4 (ἡ ἐπαγγελία τῆς παρουσίας αὐτοῦ) to a similarly parsed phrase in the John 19:25 (ἡ ἀδελφὴ τῆς μητρὸς αὐτου), what valid conclusion, if any, is found?

Similar parsing is also found in Mark 15:26, Ephesians 1:18, Revelation 11:19 and 14:7.

If ἡ ἐπαγγελία of 2 Peter 3:4, is not τῆς παρουσίας αὐτοῦ, then to what/whom does ἡ ἐπαγγελία refer?

Answer (score 4):

Your question may confuse some who assume that you are referring to some sort of *contextual* similarity between the phrase ἡ ἐπαγγελία τῆς παρουσίας αὐτοῦ ("the promise of his presence") in [2 Pet. 3:4](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=2Pe&c=3&v=4&t=KJV#s=t_conc_1159004) and the phrase ἡ ἀδελφὴ τῆς μητρὸς αὐτου ("the sister of his mother") in [John 19:25](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jhn&c=19&v=25&t=KJV#s=1016025). However, it seems the only similarity you are referring to is syntactical. That is, both phrases share the same syntax:

- [definite article declined in nominative case, singular number] +
- [noun declined in nominative case, singular number] +
- [definite article declined in genitive case, singular number] +
- [noun declined in genitive case, singular number] +
- [3rd person, personal pronoun, declined in genitive case, singular number, **masculine** (context precludes neuter gender, although it is grammatically possible) gender]

Although these two phrases share the same syntax, the genitive construction expresses a different idea in each phrase.

In the latter phrase, the genitive construction would be categorized as a possessive genitive, and therefore, it would be understood as "his mother's sister" (i.e., his aunt) rather than, say, a genitive of apposition which would be understood as "the mother, that is, his sister" (i.e., his sister is his mother).

In the former phrase, the genitive construction would **not** likely be a possessive genitive. I see you asked the same question in another forum and received some great responses:

http://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1859

I personally think there is merit in the NET Bible's belief that the former phrase is an attributed (note: not attributive) genitive, and it would thus be understood as "his promised presence" (some translate the noun παρουσία as "coming").

In summary, although two phrases may share the same syntax with genitive constructions, the genitive construction in Greek may be understood in different ways.

See the following PDF for more information:
http://www.ntgreek.org/pdf/genitive_case.pdf

Comment: I realize you have expressed knowledge in Greek grammar, so the elementary knowledge which I shared is more for the audience who reads your post, not necessarily for yourself.

Comment: I look for a bit more clarification. What is the reasoning for handling the Greek construction differently in these two verses? I was hoping not to go to the “next” level discussion about categorization, but how is one verse justifiably a possessive genitive while the other is a genitive of apposition? What knowledge do you (and others) have that permits that conclusion?

Comment: I think the latter is an attributed genitive, not genitive of apposition.

Comment: What is it about the text that has you to think this?